# MS AppFabric set maxbuffersize

Tags: caching, appfabric

I have a problem in appfabric , I configured server and client but always getting this error. if object size is bigger than 8M ,I am getting this error,

> Additional information: There is a temporary failure. Please retry
>   later. (One or more specified cache servers are unavailable, which
>   could be caused by busy network or servers. For on-premises cache
>   clusters, also verify the following conditions. Ensure that security
>   permission has been granted for this client account, and check that
>   the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all
>   cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the server must be greater than
>   or equal to the serialized object size sent from the client.)

AppFabric Configuration:

```
    <advancedProperties>
        <partitionStoreConnectionSettings leadHostManagement="false" />
        <storeProperties rootDirSize="12" subDirSize="2" />
        <memoryPressureMonitor throttleLowPercent="4" throttleHighPercent="11" />
        <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None">
            <authorization>
                <allow users="everyone" />
                <allow users="**" />
            </authorization>
        </securityProperties>
    </advancedProperties>
```

Client configuration:

```
<dataCacheClient requestTimeout="15000" channelOpenTimeout="3000" maxConnectionsToServer="1">
<localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" ttlValue="300" objectCount="10000"/>
<clientNotification pollInterval="300" maxQueueLength="10000"/>
<hosts>
  <host name="**" cachePort="22233"/>
</hosts>
<securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None" />
<transportProperties connectionBufferSize="131072" maxBufferPoolSize="268435456"
                     maxBufferSize="8388608" maxOutputDelay="2" channelInitializationTimeout="60000"
                     receiveTimeout="600000"/>
```

Comment: You have set the maxBufferSize to 8388608 which is just over 8MB, and so if the serialised object is greater than that value, you will get the error. Set the maxBufferSize to a larger value.

Comment: .. and you don't seem to be setting the value on the server, which would be in the `transportProperties` section of `advancedProperties`

Comment: Configuration on the server side cause problems,i added transportProperties section of advancedProperties , and this worked, thank you for your response.